# Why do some functions in Python change \ to \\

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I declare pass a file to `shutil.copy` as

```
shutil.copy(r'i:\myfile.txt', r'UNC to where I want it to go')
```

I get an error

```
No such file or directory 'i:\\myfile.txt'
```

I've experienced this problem before with the os module when I have a UNC path. Usually I just get frustrated enough that I forget using the os module and just put the file path into with open() or whatever I'm using it for.

It is my understanding that placing an r before '' is supposed to cause python to ignore escape characters and treat them as string literals, but the behavior I'm seeing leads me to believe that this is not the case. For some reason it takes the `\` and changes it to `\\`.

I've seen this when using os.path.join where the `\\` at the beginning of the the UNC Path gets turned into `\\\\`.

What is the best way to pass a string literal to ensure that all escape characters are ignored and the string is preserved?

Comment: Use `"i:/myfile.txt"`.  Forward-slashes work everywhere.

Comment: The error message is interesting, it looks like your `:` is disappearing also.

Comment: You are seeing the `repr()` of the string, which uses escape sequences to make it completely unambiguous what the contents are. Whether or not the string was defined as a raw string literal has no effect on this - it only changed how backslashes were interpreted in the original literal.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid It probably went the same place that the "e" in "directory" went.

Comment: @glibdud, there must be a hungry bug randomly eating characters from the OP's computer!! It's probably best to fumigate the entire computer at this point. But on a more serious note: I can't reproduce the problem. Are you *sure* the file exists?

Comment: The omission of the ```:``` and ```e``` were typos. Adding the / worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is not being modified by Python. It's the *representation* of your string that's coming out differently.

When the error is printed, Python calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) to print the value. This function will

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(), otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object. A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a **repr**() method.

This can be very nice when debugging: if I paste that string (quotes, escapes, and all) into the REPL I'll get the string in memory that you were working with. I can use this to interactively try your `copy` command, maybe tweaking the string a bit.

If you want to see your string in a printed form, you could do

```
source_path = r'i:\myfile.txt'
target_path = r'UNC to where I want it to go'
print(f'Copying {source_path} to {target_path}...')
shutil.copy(source_path, target_path)
```